# ggforce facet_zoom - labels only on zoomed example

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I would like to label points in a scatterplot, but only those within the `facet_zoom` panel. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(ggrepel)
library(magrittr)

labels <- letters
example_values_x <- rnorm(26)
example_values_y <- rnorm(26)

df <- data.frame(labels, 
                 example_values_x, 
                 example_values_y)
df %>% ggplot(aes(y = example_values_y, 
                  x = example_values_x)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = example_values_x > 0.5) + 
  geom_label_repel(data = filter(df, example_values_x > 0.5), aes(label = labels))
```

Any idea how to make it so the labels don't also appear on the non-zoomed panel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE: The following answer works with the [GitHub version of ggforce](https://github.com/thomasp85). As of writing this, the version that's on CRAN appears to have a different interface for `facet_zoom()`, even though the package version is the same.**

First, take your subset of data being labeled and add a `zoom` column, specifying whether the data should be rendered in the zoomed panel (`TRUE`), the original panel (`FALSE`), or both (`NA`):

```
dftxt <- dplyr::filter(df, example_values_x > 0.5) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( zoom = TRUE )      ## All entries to appear in the zoom panel only
```

You can now pass this new data frame to `geom_label_repel`, while telling `facet_zoom()` to use the `zoom` column to determine where the data should be drawn:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(y = example_values_y, 
                  x = example_values_x)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = example_values_x > 0.5, zoom.data=zoom) +   # Note the zoom.data argument
  geom_label_repel(data = dftxt, aes(label = labels))
```

Note that because the original `df` doesn't have a `zoom` column, `facet_zoom()` will treat it as `NA` and draw `geom_point()` in both panels, as desired:

[image]