# ggforce facet_zoom how to annotate only zoomed graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I would like to annotate the chart only in the zoomed-in area to give details about the highlighted data.

In the following example code, the idea is to show the text "zoom only" only in the zoomed-in area.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggforce)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_zoom(x = Species == "versicolor") + 
    annotate("text", x=4, y=2, label="zoom only")
```

Text only in zoom (expected state):
[image: text only in zoom]

Text in both (current state):
[image: text in both]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927431/300187) to a similar question. The key is to create a column in the data that denotes which panel to plot to, and to pass the name of that column to `zoom.data` argument of `facet_zoom`.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov zoom.data was only added  recently. Thanks for your update.

Answer (score 4):

We can dig into the object, and set that text to be transparent (`alpha = 0`):

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(x = Species == "versicolor") + 
  annotate("text", x=4, y=2, label="zoom only")

pb <- ggplot_build(p)
pb$data[[2]][1, 'alpha'] <- 0
pg <- ggplot_gtable(pb)
plot(pg)
```

[image]